# Is it okay to use Redux Toolkit and Redux Saga together?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

is it ok to use the Redux Toolkit, even if I only create Slice in it and solve middleware via Redux Saga?

Or the best practice, in this case, is to use Redux Saga + raw Redux without Toolkit?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter, redux toolkit is just an abstraction on top of raw redux but it still functions the same, both options will work with sagas just fine.

Comment: I've decided to use Redux Toolkit after reading this articele: Why Redux Toolkit is How To Use Redux Today: https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today. About Redux Saga I'm stil researching best pratices to use Redux Toolkit + Redux Saga.

Answer (score 5):

Redux-saga is just a middleware that handles async logic better. If you have a large-scale app, redux-saga is preferred over redux-thunk. redux-saga makes the testing easier.

the difference between Redux and Redux toolkit is redux toolkit requires less code to set up and redux-toolkit uses immer.js to update the state easier.

To integrate redux-saga with redux-toolkit, you write your sagas and then combine them

```
import { all } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { firstSaga } from "./firstSaga";

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([...firstSaga]);
}
```

and then in store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import rootSaga from "./rootSaga";
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    movie: MovieReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    // adding the saga middleware here
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(sagaMiddleware),
});

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```